# Deceangli and Angles: are these two tribe names etymologically related?

Tags: etymology, indo-european

In pre-Roman times, there was a Celtic tribe in Britain, called *Deceangli*. To a layperson, this name bears an interesting resemblance to *Angles*, the name of another (Germanic) tribe that lived in the continent. Coincidentally, the Angles later invaded Britain along with the Saxons, and the name *Anglaland* (England) was coined.

Is it just a pure coincidence of names or do they both derive from a more ancient, Indo-European source?

Comment: The Welsh tribe of that name was based in NE Wales. Deceangli was the name the Romans gave to them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Rhys's Celtic Britain](http://books.google.com/books?id=VLpCAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA235&ots=0p1WEBbzvK&dq=concangii%20gangani%20ceangli&pg=PA235#v=onepage&q=concangii%20gangani%20ceangli&f=false) and Tacitus:

> **deceangli** was perhaps [de-ceangli](http://www.historyfiles.co.uk/KingListsBritain/BritainDeceangli.htm) <- **de** "from" + **concangi** <- **cangi**.

And [according to Guest's Origines Celtica](http://books.google.com/books?id=LFJAShEc8ykC&lpg=PA41&ots=IYCgo_3Jsp&dq=%60caing%60%20%27estuary%27&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q=%60caing%60%20%27estuary%27&f=false):

> **cangi** was <- **caing** "estuary"

Now compare a theory about the origin of the name Angle:

> Angle <- L **anglii** "those who dwell by the narrow water/estuary" <- **ang-** "narrow".

So there is an etymological theory which says they are both related, inasmuch as both being named for proximity to an estuary.

It's not as open and shut as that, though. These are [not the only theories of the names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angles#Etymology).
Some give Angle <- **anglii** "those who dwell at the crooked place (i.e. Jutland)"; or <-  "people of *[Ingwaz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingwaz)". Under this theory the names probably are just coincidence.

Comment: Mark, I tried to improve your answer formatting also making the "punctuation" consistent in all of the examples. Feel free to rollback or edit it again if you want to change something.

Comment: @Alenanno thank you! Looks good - I did change the arrow symbols back to <-. It's not as elegant, but is now readable on more systems.

Comment: Eheheh you're right! This one is Unicode, as far as I know: ← :)

Comment: There are experts attempting to use a modern website aimed at expert linguistics questions with systems so pre-modern that they can't render a Unicode arrow?? They will certainly have bigger problems here )-:

Answer (score -5):

It's from Sanskrit anguli meaning finger.  The Angles tribe lived on a peninsula.  England and Anglesey have similar derivation since they both protrude like fingers.

Comment: Of course it’s not from Sanskrit, a language spoken thousands of miles away that none of the people in question ever even have heard of.